# Нужно удалить ссылку

Tags: javascript

есть код

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('2 4=C D();2 n=C D();2 p=C D();2 g=C D();2 d=C D();2 r=C D();2 7="E";2 19=1z;2 24=25;2 s=\'\';2 1a=0;h 26(S){h 1A(){3("8"1B S.T){2 1b=S.T.8.o;1a=1b;u=0;v(2 i=0;i<1b;i++){2 8=S.T.8[i];2 1C=8.U.$t;2 1D=8.27.$t.1E(0,10);2 1c;v(2 k=0;k<8.F.o;k++){3(8.F[k].1F==\'28\'){1c=8.F[k].m;V}}2 1d=\'\';v(2 k=0;k<8.F.o;k++){3(8.F[k].1F==\'29\'){1d=8.F[k].m;V}}2 G=\'\';3("1e"1B 8){v(2 k=0;k<8.1e.o;k++){G=8.1e[k].2a;2 l=G.1G(\';\');3(l!=-1){G=G.1E(0,l)}d[u]=G;4[u]=1C;g[u]=1D;n[u]=1c;p[u]=1d;3(i<10){r[u]=1f}A{r[u]=1z};u=u+1}}}}}1A();7="E";O(7);1g();19=1f;1H();9.e(\'</B><a m="1I://2b.2d.1J" 1K="2e-2f: 2g; 2h-2i:2j; 1L: #2k;">2l 2m 2n 2o</a>\')}h 2p(P){1M(0,0);s=P;H(s)}h 1N(){1g();s=\'\';H(s)}h O(7){h I(x,y){2 5=4[x];4[x]=4[y];4[y]=5;2 5=g[x];g[x]=g[y];g[y]=5;2 5=n[x];n[x]=n[y];n[y]=5;2 5=d[x];d[x]=d[y];d[y]=5;2 5=p[x];p[x]=p[y];p[y]=5;2 5=r[x];r[x]=r[y];r[y]=5}v(2 i=0;i<4.o-1;i++){v(2 j=i+1;j<4.o;j++){3(7=="E"){3(4[i]>4[j]){I(i,j)}}3(7=="1h"){3(4[i]<4[j]){I(i,j)}}3(7=="1i"){3(g[i]>g[j]){I(i,j)}}3(7=="W"){3(g[i]<g[j]){I(i,j)}}3(7=="1O"){3(d[i]>d[j]){I(i,j)}}}}}h 1g(){7="1O";O(7);2 j=0;2 i=0;X(i<4.o){J=d[i];Y=j;1P{j=j+1}X(d[j]==J);i=j;1j(Y,j);3(i>4.o)V}}h 1j(1Q,1k){h 1R(x,y){2 5=4[x];4[x]=4[y];4[y]=5;2 5=g[x];g[x]=g[y];g[y]=5;2 5=n[x];n[x]=n[y];n[y]=5;2 5=d[x];d[x]=d[y];d[y]=5;2 5=p[x];p[x]=p[y];p[y]=5;2 5=r[x];r[x]=r[y];r[y]=5}v(2 i=1Q;i<1k-1;i++){v(2 j=i+1;j<1k;j++){3(4[i]>4[j]){1R(i,j)}}}}h H(P){2 Q=0;2 c=\'\';2 1S=\'2q 1l\';2 K=\'1m 1n 2r 2s 2t\';2 1T=\'2u\';2 L=\'1m 1n 2v 2w 2x\';2 1U=\'2y\';2 1o=\'\';3(7=="E"){K+=\' (2z)\';L+=\' (1p Z)\'}3(7=="1h"){K+=\' (1q)\';L+=\' (1p Z)\'}3(7=="1i"){K+=\' (1q)\';L+=\' (1p Z)\'}3(7=="W"){K+=\' (1q)\';L+=\' (2A Z)\'}3(s!=\'\'){1o=\'1m 1n 2B 2C\'}c+=\'<1V>\';c+=\'<M>\';c+=\'<6 b="f-11-1r">\';c+=\'<a m="1s:1W();" U="\'+K+\'">\'+1S+\'</a>\';c+=\'</6>\';c+=\'<6 b="f-11-1t">\';c+=\'<a m="1s:1X();" U="\'+L+\'">\'+1T+\'</a>\';c+=\'</6>\';c+=\'<6 b="f-11-1u">\';c+=\'<a m="1s:1N();" U="\'+1o+\'">\'+1U+\'</a>\';c+=\'</6>\';c+=\'<6 b="f-11-1v">\';c+=\'12 2D\';c+=\'</6>\';c+=\'</M>\';v(2 i=0;i<4.o;i++){3(P==\'\'){c+=\'<M><6 b="f-8-1r"><a m="\'+n[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a></6><6 b="f-8-1t">\'+g[i]+\'</6><6 b="f-8-1u">\'+d[i]+\'</6><6 b="f-8-1v">\'+\'<a m="\'+p[i]+\'">\'+\'12\'+\'</a>\'+\'</6></M>\';Q++}A{z=d[i].1G(P);3(z!=-1){c+=\'<M><6 b="f-8-1r"><a m="\'+n[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a></6><6 b="f-8-1t">\'+g[i]+\'</6><6 b="f-8-1u">\'+d[i]+\'</6><6 b="f-8-1v">\'+\'<a m="\'+p[i]+\'">\'+\'12\'+\'</a>\'+\'</6></M>\';Q++}}}c+=\'</1V>\';3(Q==4.o){2 13=\'<N b="f-1Y">1w 2E \'+4.o+\' 1l<B/></N>\'}A{2 13=\'<N b="f-1Y">1w \'+Q+\' 2F 2G 2H \\\'\';13+=s+\'\\\' 2I \'+4.o+\' 2J 1l<B/></N>\'}2 14=9.15("f");14.1x=13+c}h 1H(){2 j=0;2 i=0;9.e(\'<q 2K="T-2L">\');9.e(\'<q b="w-2M">\');X(i<4.o){J=d[i];9.e(\'<q b="w-2N">\');9.e(\'<a  b="w-2O-m" m="/2P/2Q/\'+J+\'">\'+J+\'</a>\');9.e(\'<q b="2R"></q>\');9.e(\'</q><q b="w-2S"><1Z>\');Y=j;2 16=\'17\';1P{3(16==\'17\'){9.e(\'<1y><q b="w-18 w-18-17">\');16=\'20\'}A{9.e(\'<1y><q b="w-18 w-18-20">\');16=\'17\'}9.e(\'<a m="\'+n[j]+\'">\'+4[j]+\'</a>\');3(r[j]==1f){9.e(\' - <21><22><N 1K="1L: 2T(2U, 0, 0);">2V !!</N> </22></21>\')};9.e(\'</q></1y>\');j=j+1}X(d[j]==J);i=j;9.e(\'</1Z></q>\');1j(Y,j);3(i>4.o)V}9.e(\'</q>\');9.e(\'</q>\')}h 1W(){3(7=="E"){7="1h"}A{7="E"}O(7);H(s)}h 1X(){3(7=="W"){7="1i"}A{7="W"}O(7);H(s)}h 23(){3(19){H(s);2 R=9.15("R")}A{2W("2X 2Y... 2Z 30 31")}}h 32(){2 14=9.15("f");14.1x=\'\';2 R=9.15("R");R.1x=\'<a m="#" 33="1M(0,0); 23(); 34.35(\'+"\'f-36\',\'37\');"+\'">?i 1w 38 39</a> <3a 3b="1I://3c.3d.1J/3e.3f"/>\'}h 3g(){v(2 i=0;i<1a;i++){9.e(\'<B>\');9.e(\'3h 3i        : \'+\'<a m="\'+n[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a>\'+\'<B>\');9.e(\'12 3j  : \'+\'<a m="\'+p[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a>\'+\'<B>\');9.e(\'<B>\')}}',62,206,'||var|if|postTitle|temp|td|sortBy|entry|document||class|tocTable|postLabels|write|toc|postDate|function|||||href|postUrl|length|postMp3|div|postBaru|postFilter||ii|for|gfg||||else|br|new|Array|titleasc|link|pll|displayToc|swapPosts|temp1|tocTool1|tocTool2|tr|span|sortPosts|filter|numDisplayed|toclink|json|feed|title|break|datenewest|while|firsti|first||header|Download|tocNote|tocdiv|getElementById|tempposition|odd|listentry|tocLoaded|numberfeed|numEntries|posturl|postmp3|category|true|sortlabel|titledesc|dateoldest|sortPosts2|lastvar|Artikel|Klik|untuk|tocTool3|newest|ascending|col1|javascript|col2|col3|col4|Menampilkan|innerHTML|li|false|getPostData|in|posttitle|postdate|substring|rel|lastIndexOf|displayToc2|http|ru|style|color|scroll|allPosts|orderlabel|do|firstvar|swapPosts2|tocHead1|tocHead2|tocHead3|table|toggleTitleSort|toggleDateSort|note|ol|even|strong|em|showToc|numChars|250|loadtoc|published|alternate|enclosure|term|www||webaffiliates|font|size|8px|text|decoration|none|616469| | |Web|Affiliates|filterPosts|Judul|sortir|berdasarkan|judul|Tanggal|Sortir|bedasarkan|tanggal|Kategori|descending|oldest|menampilkan|semua|MP3|Semua|artikel|dengan|kategori|dari|Total|id|control|root|subtitle|collapse|search|label|clearFloat|list|rgb|255|New|alert|Just|wait|TOC|is|loading|hideToc|onclick|Effect|toggle|result|blind|Daftar|Isi|img|src|radiorodja|googlepages|new_1|gif|looptemp2|Post|Link|mp3'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Из него нужно удалить url  http://www.webaffiliates.ru/ если это возможно сделать помогите пожалуста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('2 4=M L();2 n=M L();2 q=M L();2 h=M L();2 d=M L();2 r=M L();2 7="D";2 1b=1T;2 21=20;2 u=\'\';2 1l=0;g 22(16){g 1J(){3("8"1z 16.Z){2 1j=16.Z.8.o;1l=1j;v=0;s(2 i=0;i<1j;i++){2 8=16.Z.8[i];2 1S=8.S.$t;2 1M=8.2k.$t.1X(0,10);2 1r;s(2 k=0;k<8.J.o;k++){3(8.J[k].1H==\'2e\'){1r=8.J[k].m;V}}2 1f=\'\';s(2 k=0;k<8.J.o;k++){3(8.J[k].1H==\'2h\'){1f=8.J[k].m;V}}2 K=\'\';3("1a"1z 8){s(2 k=0;k<8.1a.o;k++){K=8.1a[k].2c;2 l=K.1U(\';\');3(l!=-1){K=K.1X(0,l)}d[v]=K;4[v]=1S;h[v]=1M;n[v]=1r;q[v]=1f;3(i<10){r[v]=1e}A{r[v]=1T};v=v+1}}}}}1J();7="D";R(7);1w();1b=1e;1C()}g 29(P){1V(0,0);u=P;C(u)}g 1P(){1w();u=\'\';C(u)}g R(7){g F(x,y){2 6=4[x];4[x]=4[y];4[y]=6;2 6=h[x];h[x]=h[y];h[y]=6;2 6=n[x];n[x]=n[y];n[y]=6;2 6=d[x];d[x]=d[y];d[y]=6;2 6=q[x];q[x]=q[y];q[y]=6;2 6=r[x];r[x]=r[y];r[y]=6}s(2 i=0;i<4.o-1;i++){s(2 j=i+1;j<4.o;j++){3(7=="D"){3(4[i]>4[j]){F(i,j)}}3(7=="1v"){3(4[i]<4[j]){F(i,j)}}3(7=="1y"){3(h[i]>h[j]){F(i,j)}}3(7=="T"){3(h[i]<h[j]){F(i,j)}}3(7=="1Q"){3(d[i]>d[j]){F(i,j)}}}}}g 1w(){7="1Q";R(7);2 j=0;2 i=0;Y(i<4.o){G=d[i];14=j;1Y{j=j+1}Y(d[j]==G);i=j;1u(14,j);3(i>4.o)V}}g 1u(1B,1s){g 1Z(x,y){2 6=4[x];4[x]=4[y];4[y]=6;2 6=h[x];h[x]=h[y];h[y]=6;2 6=n[x];n[x]=n[y];n[y]=6;2 6=d[x];d[x]=d[y];d[y]=6;2 6=q[x];q[x]=q[y];q[y]=6;2 6=r[x];r[x]=r[y];r[y]=6}s(2 i=1B;i<1s-1;i++){s(2 j=i+1;j<1s;j++){3(4[i]>4[j]){1Z(i,j)}}}}g C(P){2 O=0;2 c=\'\';2 1K=\'2a 1n\';2 I=\'1p 1m 28 27 24\';2 1D=\'25\';2 E=\'1p 1m 26 23 2b\';2 1W=\'2i\';2 1d=\'\';3(7=="D"){I+=\' (2j)\';E+=\' (19 11)\'}3(7=="1v"){I+=\' (1g)\';E+=\' (19 11)\'}3(7=="1y"){I+=\' (1g)\';E+=\' (19 11)\'}3(7=="T"){I+=\' (1g)\';E+=\' (2g 11)\'}3(u!=\'\'){1d=\'1p 1m 2d 2f\'}c+=\'<1I>\';c+=\'<N>\';c+=\'<5 b="f-U-1h">\';c+=\'<a m="1q:1G();" S="\'+I+\'">\'+1K+\'</a>\';c+=\'</5>\';c+=\'<5 b="f-U-1o">\';c+=\'<a m="1q:1E();" S="\'+E+\'">\'+1D+\'</a>\';c+=\'</5>\';c+=\'<5 b="f-U-1i">\';c+=\'<a m="1q:1P();" S="\'+1d+\'">\'+1W+\'</a>\';c+=\'</5>\';c+=\'<5 b="f-U-1k">\';c+=\'15 2u\';c+=\'</5>\';c+=\'</N>\';s(2 i=0;i<4.o;i++){3(P==\'\'){c+=\'<N><5 b="f-8-1h"><a m="\'+n[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a></5><5 b="f-8-1o">\'+h[i]+\'</5><5 b="f-8-1i">\'+d[i]+\'</5><5 b="f-8-1k">\'+\'<a m="\'+q[i]+\'">\'+\'15\'+\'</a>\'+\'</5></N>\';O++}A{z=d[i].1U(P);3(z!=-1){c+=\'<N><5 b="f-8-1h"><a m="\'+n[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a></5><5 b="f-8-1o">\'+h[i]+\'</5><5 b="f-8-1i">\'+d[i]+\'</5><5 b="f-8-1k">\'+\'<a m="\'+q[i]+\'">\'+\'15\'+\'</a>\'+\'</5></N>\';O++}}}c+=\'</1I>\';3(O==4.o){2 12=\'<B b="f-1F">1c 2T \'+4.o+\' 1n<H/></B>\'}A{2 12=\'<B b="f-1F">1c \'+O+\' 2U 2V 2W \\\'\';12+=u+\'\\\' 2S \'+4.o+\' 2R 1n<H/></B>\'}2 17=9.18("f");17.1x=12+c}g 1C(){2 j=0;2 i=0;9.e(\'<p 2N="Z-2M">\');9.e(\'<p b="w-2O">\');Y(i<4.o){G=d[i];9.e(\'<p b="w-2P">\');9.e(\'<a  b="w-2l-m" m="/2Y/2Q/\'+G+\'">\'+G+\'</a>\');9.e(\'<p b="2X"></p>\');9.e(\'</p><p b="w-34"><1A>\');14=j;2 X=\'13\';1Y{3(X==\'13\'){9.e(\'<1t><p b="w-W w-W-13">\');X=\'1R\'}A{9.e(\'<1t><p b="w-W w-W-1R">\');X=\'13\'}9.e(\'<a m="\'+n[j]+\'">\'+4[j]+\'</a>\');3(r[j]==1e){9.e(\' - <1L><1N><B 35="32: 2Z(30, 0, 0);">33 !!</B> </1N></1L>\')};9.e(\'</p></1t>\');j=j+1}Y(d[j]==G);i=j;9.e(\'</1A></p>\');1u(14,j);3(i>4.o)V}9.e(\'</p>\');9.e(\'</p>\')}g 1G(){3(7=="D"){7="1v"}A{7="D"}R(7);C(u)}g 1E(){3(7=="T"){7="1y"}A{7="T"}R(7);C(u)}g 1O(){3(1b){C(u);2 Q=9.18("Q")}A{31("2K 2t... 2L 2v 2w")}}g 2s(){2 17=9.18("f");17.1x=\'\';2 Q=9.18("Q");Q.1x=\'<a m="#" 2r="1V(0,0); 1O(); 2n.2m(\'+"\'f-2o\',\'2p\');"+\'">?i 1c 2q 2x</a> <2y 2G="2H://2I.2J.2F/2E.2A"/>\'}g 2z(){s(2 i=0;i<1l;i++){9.e(\'<H>\');9.e(\'2B 2C       : \'+\'<a m="\'+n[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a>\'+\'<H>\');9.e(\'15 2D  : \'+\'<a m="\'+q[i]+\'">\'+4[i]+\'</a>\'+\'<H>\');9.e(\'<H>\')}}',62,192,'||var|if|postTitle|td|temp|sortBy|entry|document||class|tocTable|postLabels|write|toc|function|postDate|||||href|postUrl|length|div|postMp3|postBaru|for||postFilter|ii|gfg||||else|span|displayToc|titleasc|tocTool2|swapPosts|temp1|br|tocTool1|link|pll|Array|new|tr|numDisplayed|filter|toclink|sortPosts|title|datenewest|header|break|listentry|tempposition|while|feed||first|tocNote|odd|firsti|Download|json|tocdiv|getElementById|newest|category|tocLoaded|Menampilkan|tocTool3|true|postmp3|ascending|col1|col3|numEntries|col4|numberfeed|untuk|Artikel|col2|Klik|javascript|posturl|lastvar|li|sortPosts2|titledesc|sortlabel|innerHTML|dateoldest|in|ol|firstvar|displayToc2|tocHead2|toggleDateSort|note|toggleTitleSort|rel|table|getPostData|tocHead1|strong|postdate|em|showToc|allPosts|orderlabel|even|posttitle|false|lastIndexOf|scroll|tocHead3|substring|do|swapPosts2|250|numChars|loadtoc|bedasarkan|judul|Tanggal|Sortir|berdasarkan|sortir|filterPosts|Judul|tanggal|term|menampilkan|alternate|semua|oldest|enclosure|Kategori|descending|published|collapse|toggle|Effect|result|blind|Daftar|onclick|hideToc|wait|MP3|is|loading|Isi|img|looptemp2|gif|Post|Link|mp3|new_1|ru|src|http|radiorodja|googlepages|Just|TOC|control|id|root|subtitle|label|Total|dari|Semua|artikel|dengan|kategori|clearFloat|search|rgb|255|alert|color|New|list|style'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Думаю работать должно)))

Comment: Спасибо) Огромное Вам спасибо) Очень помогли)